# Why does Android-Things app crash on new ConnectionFactory

Tags: rabbitmq, android-things

Attempting to use RabbitMQ in AndroidThings project but app crashes at
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
Console error A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x68 in tid 3083 (an.rabbitmqtest), pid 3083 (an.rabbitmqtest)

I have included  uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" in manifest

My test project for just the connection.

Gradle includes implementation 'com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:+'

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setupConnectionFactory();

  }

  // next line is the problem!
  ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();

  private void setupConnectionFactory() {
    String uri = "CLOUDAMQP_URL";
    try {
        factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(false);
        factory.setUri(uri);
    } catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | 
             URISyntaxException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem for now by forcing the old AMQP client lib in Gradle.
com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:4.11.+
Maybe a bug in the latest 5.7 AMQP lib, I am running JRE 1.8.... so would have thought this should work.